# Regexp catch latest child

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to catch `"(<tag>(.*?)</tag>)"`, but only the latest child, so for example `<tag><tag>...</tag></tag>` should be ignored.

Is this possible to do using only one regexp in PHP?

Code:

```
------------------------

<tag>
    <tag>
        <tag>
            <i> abcd <\/i>
        </tag>
    </tag>
</tag>

<tag>
    <tag>
        efgh
    </tag>
</tag>

------------------------

<tag>
    ijkl
</tag>

<tag>
    mnop
</tag>

------------------------
```

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I think that using xquery is a better option for this

Comment: I know that it is not the best method, but I must to break this rule. :P

Comment: If you need to break a rule, it is helpful to explain why, so readers can have a better idea of how to advise.

Comment: because very old program can be fed only by one regexp string as argument. The program is doing too many things in black box, so i can not simply rewrite source or write new program. Program usually was fed by text files without html or any other tagged language, but very rarely, for example - now, i want to give him one file written in tagged language ;P

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex and catch the capturing group:

```
.*<\/?tag>|(.*<\/.*?>)$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zR1qK7/2)**

[image]

Btw, if you want to get the full line with whatever content inside tags (like efg and mnop) you could use this one:

```
.*<\/?tag>|(.+)$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zR1qK7/4)**

Comment: abcd, efgh, ijkl, mnop should be green sorrounded with only one pair of tag

Comment: You're mistaken. Suppose there's a string within some other `<tag>` tags